How to dynamically access keys and values of a struct in Zig?
How can one define a function that takes a struct in Zig and be able to access all the keys and values In that struct dynamically?
I have tried a couple of approaches but I kept getting compile error.
For example
pub fn keyValue(input: anytype) {

      switch (@typeInfo(@TypeOf(input))) {
        .Struct => |struc| {
            for (struc.fields) |field| {
                std.debug.print("{any}", .{field});
            }
        },
        else => {
            unreachable();
        },
    }

}

I get this compile error
src/trace_ng/logfmt.zig:44:23: error: values of type '[]const builtin.Type.StructField' must be comptime-known, but index value is runtime-known
            for (struc.fields) |field| {
                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~
/Users/.zvm/0.13.0/lib/std/builtin.zig:346:15: note: struct requires comptime because of this field
        type: type,
              ^~~~
/Users/.zvm/0.13.0/lib/std/builtin.zig:346:15: note: types are not available at runtime
        type: type,
              ^~~~
/Users/.zvm/0.13.0/lib/std/builtin.zig:349:20: note: struct requires comptime because of this field
        alignment: comptime_int,

How may I dynamically get the fields and values of those fields of a struct in Zig?

inline for(struc.fields) |field| std.debug.print("{any}", .{@field(input, field.name});

@FObersteiner anytype is always comptime known, the type for values of any type which are not comptime known would be *anyopaque.

@Cubic thanks for clarifying. It seems that inline for indeed does the trick. So I guess the point here is that the compiler does not attempt to inline the loop unless you tell it to do so.
